# Overriding route in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.4

I have one trouble in routing in CakePHP. I have index action of all customers. And the question is, is there a way to make it this way, when I go to `/..../.../customers` CakePhp renders index(as per default), but when I am going to `/..../.../customers.json`(in .json format), CakePhp renders another action, where some array is serialized. I already enabled mapping resources, so it works just fine without overriding, but is there some way I can implement this ?
I've already read https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html.

Comment: Did you try to debug "$this->request->ext" and if it's return 'json' you do your serialized array else you do the normal action ?

Comment: @Gransfall, Thanks, that worked, I just check if the request if json like `if(isset($this->request->ext['json'])) and just render it in the needed ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, [Gransfall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7405557/gransfall).  I just check if the request is json and then load the view in the need way.

```
if(isset($this->request->params['ext'])){
    if($this->request->params['ext']=='json'){
          //here setting serialized array
     }
}
```